# JSON object does not update correctly

Tags: html, jquery

First of all, I'm not sure if my title describes the problem correctly... I did search but didn't find anything that helped me out...

The project I'm working on has an `#orderList`. All orders have a delete option. After an order gets deleted the list is updated.

Sounds simple... I ran into a problem though.

```
/**
 * Data returned at the end of selecting some options
 */
$.post(myUrl, $('#myForm').serialize(), function(data) {
    // I build the orderlist
    // The data returned is a JSON object holding session data (including orders)
    buildOrderList(data);
    ...
    // Do some other work
});

/*
 * function to build the html list
 */
function buildOrderList(data) {
    // Empty list
    $('#orderList').empty();

    // The click handler for the delete button is in here because it needs the data object
    $(document).on('click', '[id^=delete_]', function() {
        // Get the orderId from the delete button
        var orderId = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        orderId = orderId['1'];
        // I call the delete function
        deleteOrder(orderId, data);
    });

    var html = '';
    // Loop the data object
    $.each(data, function(key,val){
        ...
        // Put html code needed in var html
        ...
    });
    $('#orderList').append(html);
}

/*
 * function to delete an order
 */
function deleteOrder(orderId, data) {
    // Because of it depends on other 'products' in the list if the user can
    // simply delete it, I use a jQuery dialog to give him some options.
    // These options I send to a php script so it knows what should be deleted.
    // This fires when a user clicks on the 'delete' button from a dialog.
    // The dialog uses data to show options but does not change the value of data.
    switch(data.type) {
        case 'A':
            delMsg += '<p>Some message for case A</p>';
            delMsg += '<select>with some options for case A</select>';
            $('#wizard_dialog').append(delMsg);
            $('#wizard_dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons',  [ 
                { text: "Delete", click: function() { 
                        $.post(myUrl, $('#myDeleteOptions').serialize(), function(newData) {
                            // Now the returned data is the updated session data
                            // So I build the orderList again...
                            buildOrderList(newData);
                            ...
                            // Do some other work
                        });
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        $(this).html(''); }},
                { text: "Cancel", click: function() { $( this ).dialog("close"); $(this).html(''); }}
            ] );
            break;
        case 'B':
            // Do the same thing but different text and <select> elements
            break;
    }
}
```

The `orderList` updates correctly, however if I try to delete another order, the jQuery dialog gives me the option for the current (correct product) AND the option for the product that previously owned the id of the current. (Hope I didn't loose anyone in my attempt to explain the problem)

The main question is how to 'refresh' the data send to `buildOrderList`.

Since I call the function in a new $.post with fresh data object returned it should work, shouldn't it?

```
/**
 * Enable the JQuery dialog
 * (#wizard_dialog)
     * this is the init (note that I only open the dialog in deleteOrder() and set text and buttons according to the data send to deleteOrder() )
 */
$('#wizard_dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    open: function() {
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Annuleren")').addClass('cancelButtonClass');
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Verwijderen")').addClass('deleteButtonClass');
        $('.ui-dialog :button').blur(); // Because it is dangerous to put focus on 'OK' button
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('position', 'fixed'); // Fixing overlay (else in wrong position?)
        if ($(document).height() > $(window).height()) {
            var scrollTop = ($('html').scrollTop()) ? $('html').scrollTop() : $('body').scrollTop(); // Works for Chrome, Firefox, IE...
            $('html').addClass('noscroll').css('top',-scrollTop); // Prevent scroll without hiding the bar (thus preventing page to shift)
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('position', 'absolute'); // Brake overlay again
        var scrollTop = parseInt($('html').css('top'));
        $('html').removeClass('noscroll'); // Allow scrolling again
        $('html,body').scrollTop(-scrollTop);
        $('#wizard_dialog').html('');
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**
Because the problem could be in the dialog I added some code.
In the first code block I changed deleteOrder();

**ANSWER**
The solution was rather simple. I forgot to turn the click handler off before I added the new one. This returned the previous event and the new event.

```
$(document).off('click', '[id^=delete_]').on('click', '[id^=delete_]', function() {
        // Get the orderId from the delete button
        var orderId = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        orderId = orderId['1'];
        // I call the delete function
        deleteOrder(orderId, data);
    });
```

Comment: mention that problem is with dialog, but no code shown regarding dialog and how you create relationship between item and dialog

Comment: in the deleteOrder() I always open a dialog where I put a message and some <select> elements. the $.post will trigger when a user hits 'delete' instead of 'cancel'. No other functions are in the dialog.

Comment: anyone can help me out ?

Comment: really not clear what problem is. When you close dialog you empty it, but no code shown to fill the html again. Is likely that code that is causing problems if you say you get multiple options showing in dialog

Comment: I Added the solution. Problem had nothing to do with the dialog. I had to unbind the click event before adding a new one. Since the order object got renumbered after a product got deleted the element got 2 click events attached to it. Stupid me :)

Comment: forgot to mention...that click handler shouldn't be inside your function.

Comment: Not even if I need to pass the data var to it? That var isn't available outside the deleteOrder function.